# Sugar ORM как сделать вывод строки по id?

Tags: android, sugarorm

Есть EditText (id), TextView(text), Button(show) и занесенные в БД значения.
Мне нужно вытащить из БД значение по id и отобразить в text с помощью Sugar ORM.

```
 case R.id.show:
 String identifier = id.getText.toString(); 
 Contact сontact = Contact.findById(Contact.class, identifier);
 text.setText(contact.toString());
 break;
```

Вот в таком виде пробовал все это дело запускать но не получается. Нормального гайда по Sugar ORM найти не приходилось. Если у кого нибудь есть нормальные источники на примете чтобы разобраться в нем, буду благодарен за ссылку.

Comment: Что конкретно не получается? Вылетает ошибка? Попробуйте залогировать все изменения переменных и посмотреть что у вас там происходит. Если вылетает ошибка- приложите в вашему вопросу stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

В findById вторым аргументом нужно передавать переменную типа int, поэтому смею предположить, что indetifier нужно преобразовать в переменную все того же типа int.